# InstallShield shortcut links going to wrong directory

Tags: c#, installshield

I've created a project in Visual Studios 2010, and when I package it with InstallShield, I click new -> pick the primary output file, rename it, and then click the desktop option as well. It properly creates the shortcuts to both the start menu and the desktop, but they don't point to the correct location. If I go straight to the Program Files x86 folder and click on the .exe, the program loads correctly. If I click on either of the links, it fails

Comment: Is this Installshield LE? What sort of Installshield project are you creating?

Comment: Did you check the properties of the shortcut as which path it is pointing to ?

Comment: did you got a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Go to InstallShield Project -> Configure the Target System -> Shortcuts/Folders

Select your shourtcut and Set your Working Directory ([INSTALLDIR]) in Behavior Property.
Do the same for your start menu.

It worked for me in Installshield 2013.