# InstallShield shortcut links going to a wrong database path or "is not a valid path"

Tags: c#, installshield-le

I  made a project in Visual Studios 2013, and when I build it with InstallShield,click new -> pick the primary output file, and database is Health.accdb. after that, I installed it in my desktop . It properly creates the shortcuts to both the start menu and the desktop, but they don't point to the correct location. If I go straight to the Program Files x86 folder and click on the .exe, the program loads correctly. If I click on either of the links/Shortcuts, it fails or not correct path.

I'm using this connection for my database in c# winform:

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Database/Health.accdb;");
```

Comment: This question is answered in below link. Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531935/installshield-shortcut-links-going-to-wrong-directory/54307077#54307077